# How to dynamically list all methods from a class whithin a module

Tags: python-2.7

I have a few modules that i want to import dynamically. 
These modules contain classes that in turn have their own methods.

Is there a way to list the classes methods and more over get access to their internal variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the dir(ClassInQuestion) function the one you are looking for? You should get all Methods and Properties.